# AWS ECS - Can't connect to RabbitMQ EC2 instance from ECS container instance on the same subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, rabbitmq, amazon-ecs

I am building an application where I will have multiple `Docker services` running on `ECS container instance` communicating with each other via `RabbitMQ` which runs on a separate `EC2 instance` in the same `VPC`and in the same subnet. The `RabbitMQ` security group is configured to allow all the traffic from that subnet.

However, when I start the `service` and it tries to connect to `RabbitMQ` I get an error saying `ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5672`. This is the url that I am using t connect `amqp://username:password@ipaddr:5672/?heartbeat=60`. The network mode for `Docker` is `default/Bridge`.

I am setting the connection url via an environment variable and I did `ssh` into the `ECS` container instance and then `docker exec -it cntainerID /bin/bash` and was able to verify that the environment variable is set.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to 127.0.0.1? You should use the rabbitmq host ip address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`127.0.0.1` is not the IP address of the EC2 RabbitMQ server. That address will always point to what ever machine the code is running on, it is called "localhost".

You need to be using the **private IP** of the EC2 server running RabbitMQ.

Comment: In a Docker context 127.0.0.1 usually resolves to _this container_, which is different from the machine as a whole.

Comment: @DavidMaze yes physical machine/virtual machine/container, `127.0.0.1` is going to resolve to the "local" environment, which is certainly not correct in the context of the question being asked.

Comment: @MarkB Thanks for your answer! Indeed the `ipaddr` was incorrect, I had a typo in my environment variable.